# Top 100 Charts copyright

Tags: copyright, internet, intellectual-property

Am I breaking copyright if use the Billboard Hot 100 chart on my own website but in a different format and adding data, I created, to it.

On the website I am displaying this modified chart and letting users interact with it.
The interaction is a form of gamification.

I have read this [article](http://www.lib.umich.edu/copyright-office-mpublishing/copyrightability-charts-tables-and-graphs#sdfootnote4anc) which says:

> Charts, graphs, and tables are not subject to copyright protection
>   because they do not meet the first requirement for copyright
>   protection, that is, they are not “original works of authorship,”
>   under the definitions in the Act.

The state of law seems really muddy on this topic and I would be grateful for some clarification.

**Further clarification** - what I am using is:

1. The list of songs for that week's billboard chart. So only the names of the songs, without particular ordering.
2. The facts whether the song has risen or fallen compared to the previous week.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copyright facts. The number of records sold in a week is a fact.

Comment: The list may have been developed based on labor intensive collection of sales data.   My untrained thought(I am not a lawyer) is that if you collect the data yourself, you are save.  But if you just use the list that someone else developed you may run afoul of copyright law.  I have heard that map makers include some errors in their maps so they can identify illegal copies.

Comment: @user3270 the Op is saying specifically that he is not copying the format, only the information. Map makers cannot copyright the location of New York City.

Comment: Depending on your location you may be breaking the law, even if not the copyright law. For example you may be in breach of competition laws if you let others do the work and then just copy their works.

Comment: @user3270, the United States does not have a "sweat of the brow" copyright law.  The amount of effort put into making something does not, in and of itself, grant any rights.

Comment: Some countries like the UK and EU recognise [database rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_right) but the US doesn't, so you are safe there. Although as the internet is worldwide you might consider the situation around the world in case you ever expand or do business internationally.